# How to set background image to shell or composite in SWT

Tags: eclipse-plugin, swt

```java
public class createShell{

        System.out.println("Inside shell create");
        display = new Display();
        shell = new Shell(display);
        shell.setSize(990, 590);
       
        shell.setLayout(new GridLayout());
        
        Composite comp = new Composite(shell, SWT.NO_FOCUS);
        comp.setBounds(10, 10, 720, 400);
        
}
```

I have existing code like this. Need to set a background image to shell. How to give relative path of image.
The folder structure of plug-in(com.vcc.rac.ks5lmpp) is as per image.[path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X3FGu.png) The code file is in package inside src folder(plugins\com.rac.ks5lmpp\src\com\kjj\rac\ks5lmpp\stylesheets\dialogs\createShell.java)
There exists a image folder(plugins\com.rac.ks5lmpp\src\com\kjj\rac\ks5lmpp\stylesheets\dialogs\images) in which the image is there which I want to pass as background.
Image size is of 676X324 of PNG type.

Thanks in advance.

[image: path]

Comment: Is this an Eclipse plug-in? You use FileLocator in plug-in to find images.

Comment: Yes this is Eclipse pug in and used for Teamcenter development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use `FileLocator` in an Eclipse plug-in to find resources in the plug-in.

```java
Bundle bundle = FrameworkUtil.getBundle(getClass()); // Or some other way to find the current bundle

URL url = FileLocator.find(bundle, new Path("path within the plugin"));

ImageDescriptor desc = ImageDescriptor.createFromURL(url);

Image image = desc.createImage();

shell.setBackgroundImage(image);
```

Note: You should arrange to dispose of the image when the shell closes.

Be sure that the `build.properties` for the plug-in includes the images.

`FileLocator` is `org.eclipse.core.runtime.FileLocator`.

`Path` is `org.eclipse.core.runtime.Path` (not the java.nio.file Path)

`ImageDescriptor` is `org.eclipse.jface.resource.ImageDescriptor`

Comment: Thanks....!!! It worked well. Just one help I need to make a button which should be hidden/not visible on image but when user clicks on image , I need to pass a selection using button selection listener. Just need help with the thing how to hide button keeping it active.